# Code editor to find in files using CSS selectors / Emmet abbreviations?

Tags: text-editor, ide, css, html-editor, file-search

Which code editor or IDE allows me to find a CSS selector or Emmet abbreviation in files of my project?

For example, I type `.parent .child` in the find box and I should get files containg both:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.parent {
    .child {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Element Finder](https://github.com/keeganstreet/element-finder)** is an app for recursively searching through a directory and finding HTML files which contain elements matching a given CSS selector. There is also a [Sublime Text plugin](https://github.com/keeganstreet/sublime-elfinder).